# google compute engine transfer external ip address, MAC address, name

Tags: redhat, google-compute-engine

I have an RHEL7 GCE instance with a static external IP#, a domain name registered through Google Cloud DNS, an SSL certificate generated against its static external IP#, and software licenses registered against its MAC address.  I have corrupted the OS and I want to replace the instance with a newly created one. I need to transfer those network identifiers and the instance name to a new instance. The new instance can be created in the same project as the old instance. So how do I:

```
1. Assign the old instance's external IP# to the new instance (and give the old instance a new IP#)?
2. Assign the old instance's MAC address to the new instance (and give the old instance a new MAC address)?
3. Transfer the instance name from the old one to the new one (and rename the old one to something else)?
```

Completing any of those will save me a lot of trouble, and all of them will save me a huge load of trouble.

Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1):

OK, working through these:

1. Transfer external IP#:

   A. Ensure the old instance's external IP# is static, not ephemeral. That status makes the IP# a property of the instance's project, not just the instance it's assigned to. Deleting the old instance doesn't release that IP#, just changes its status from IN_USE to RESERVED . Check its status with `gcloud compute addresses list` .

   B. Delete the old instance. External IP# is retained; check its status with `gcloud compute addresses list` .

   C. Create the new instance. As per ["Configuring IP Addresses" > "Assigning a static external IP address to a new VM instance"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#assign_new_instance):
   `gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME] --address [IP_ADDRESS]` or from the GCE admin console webpage when specifying properties of the instance you're creating:

   > Expand the Management, disk, networking, SSH keys section. Click
   >   Networking. Under External IP, select a static external IP address

   Select the option that is the RESERVED external static IP# you are reusing.

   D. Complete creating the new instance, and the old external static IP# is transferred to it.
2. Transfer MAC address: There is no documented method to change an instance MAC address that allows the instance to resume connectivity afterwards.
3. Transfer instance name: It's immutable, so no go.

1 out of 3 is better than none.

Comment: Instead of deleting the old instance to remove its static external IP# (returning it to the project's RESERVED pool), you can just remove the IP# from the instance: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#unassign_ip